# RedisLabs Enterprise Cluster stopping the service

Tags: services, redis

I am running RedisLabs Enterprise Cluster in my Desktop and Laptop(both running Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS). In my desktop - the RedisLabs Enterprise Cluster stops if i restart but in case of my laptop it is not?
How to stop RLEC services?
The only difference in both of them is that laptop - I have upgraded the kernel version to 4.2.5 while Desktop it is still 3.1 or 3.2
Last time I fixed this problem by uninstalling RLEC altogether.

[image]

I can kill some of these processes but it's not helping much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the official documents from RedisLab. Found this [link](https://redislabs.com/blog/getting-started-with-rlec-how-to-install-and-setup#.VrpLG5MrKgQ)

Deleted the directory

```
rm -rf /var/opt/redislabs/persist
```

and then using ps -aux | grep redis
found out all the processes like RedisManager and others and then killed them using

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Not very clean way but it at least bring down the CPU levels in control. After restart some of the processes are back again. It seems if i don't get a more graceful way of shutting down RLEC...better to uninstall it.
[image]

Finally purging it

```
apt-get purge redis*
rm -rf /etc/opt/redislabs/
```

And this seems to be the only way to control it sadly.

Got some communications from Redis team and according to them , one should use the following commands to stop it:

```
cd /opt/redislabs/bin/
sudo ./cnm_ctl stop
sudo ./redis_ctl stop–all
sudo ./dmcproxy stop
```

Comment: just slight correction, there is no space between stop and -all. Should be stop-all